# How can I add a delay of 90 minutes when a port has gone from 0 to 1?

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I have a PIC12F1822 of which there is an LED and relay as an output and a trigger as an input.

When the trigger is equal to one, I would like the to have the LED and relay stay turned on for 90 minutes.

The problem is that I cannot use a delay since __delayms has a limit.

How can this be done?

```
#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

#define LED PORTAbits.RA5
#define RELAY PORTAbits.RA4
#define TRIGGER PORTAbits.RA2

int main()
{

//  OSCCON = 0b01101000 ;
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b1101 ;

  TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0; //LED Output PIN
  TRISAbits.TRISA4 = 0; //Output for Relay
  TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 1; //INPUT trigger from comparator

  while(1)
  {
      if (TRIGGER == 1)
      { 
          LED = 1;  // LED ON
          __delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
          LED = 0;  // LED OFF
          __delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay

       }

      else

      {
       LED = 0;  // LED OFF   
      }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why not wrap the 1s delay in a function providing a `delay_s(uint32_t seconds)` and in a function providing a `delay_m(uint32_t minutes)`

```
void delay_s(uint32_t seconds)
{
  while(seconds){
    __delay_ms(1000);
    seconds--;
  }
}

void delay_m(uint32_t minutes)
{
  while(minutes){
    delay_s(60);
    minutes--;
  }
}
```

But:
You should be aware that this totally blocks your µC's program.
It will not react on any key press. This may be ok but may be you want the delay to be reset to  90min if the key is pressed during the delay.

I would suggest to implement the whole thing with interrupts and timers.
Set up a timer that triggers once every second and countdown a global variable (`volatile`!) within the isr that was set by your main loop. If the counter reaches 0 your isr may disable your output.

This way your µC can process other things in the mainloop and is not blocked by a `__delay`-function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought about making something like this but I don't knlw if it's a good idea.

Comment: How would you use interrupts and timers? Are there any examples?

Comment: As you have noted, this will block everything.  Threading has to come into play to avoid that.

Comment: @M2T156 you have to Look this up at your tool chain documents, as this depends on different things

Answer (score 1):

Simple. [State machines](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m520736.aspx) and [timer interrupts](https://microchipdeveloper.com/8bit:timer0int) and a minute countdown. Something like this:

*Disclaimer - coded blindly*

```
#define MINUTES_90 5400UL /* 90 seconds */

typedef enum
{
    /** Code operational */
    p_state_idle,
    /** Code waiting for 90 minutes */
    p_state_waiting
}p_state_t;

static unsigned long gSecondsRemaining = MINUTES_90;

int main()
{
    p_state_t gState = p_state_running;

    OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0; /* Prescaler assigned */
    OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b111; /* 256 prescaler */
    OPTION_REGbits.TMR0CS = 0; /* Fosc / 4 */
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1; /* Timer 0 interrupt enabled */
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; /* Peripheral interrupts enabled */
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1; /* Global interrupts enabled */

    /** Default LED off */
    LED = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        switch (gState)
        {
        case p_state_idle:
            if (TRIGGER == 1)
            {
                LED = 1;  // LED ON
                gSecondsRemaining = MINUTES_90; /* Reset timer countdown */
                gState = p_state_waiting;
            }
            break;
        case p_state_waiting:
            /** can sleep here */
            if (gSecondsRemaining == 0)
            {
                gState = p_state_idle;
                LED = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void interrupt ISR()
{
    static unsigned char gSecond = 15;

    /** approx 15 Hz ? */
    if (INTCONbits.TMR0IF)
    {
        INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;

        if (gSecond > 0)
            gSecond--;

        if (gSecond == 0)
        {
            if (gSecondsRemaining > 0)
                gSecondsRemaining--;

            gSecond = 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with an inline assembly function with some loops. Have a look here: [example: 30 min delay](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m396039.aspx)